# android: buttons on top of imageview in multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, image, button, size, screen

Hi I'm developing an app on android and I have some layouts where I would like to have an image that fills the `screen-width` in landscape mode. On top of that, i want some buttons on specific places.

I used a `scrollview` (because the image doesn't fit in height if it fills the width of the screen), with a relative layout within.

In that relative layout, I put the `imageview` and the buttons. The image fills the width and wraps the content for the height. The buttons are placed through setting the left and top margins within the relative layout.

Everything is looking good on the phone i tested it with, but when i test on a different device (other screen size and density) all buttons are on the wrong place and aren't big enough anymore.

How can i change this, so that all proportions stay the same? The buttons have to be in the exact same position and have to be the same size, in comparison with the image.

My code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/svCentralAmerica"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlCentralAmerica"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCentralAmerica"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/mapcentralamerica" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mexu"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:background="@drawable/usa_y"
            android:onClick="onCountryClick"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:tag="1;U"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mexr"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/mexu"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mexu"
            android:background="@drawable/russia_n"
            android:onClick="onCountryClick"
            android:paddingTop="18dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:tag="1;R"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/Red"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: RelativeLayout is very tricky when it comes to different screen densities, you'll have to do it programmatically to set their location and sizes based on screen size

Answer (score 0):

I have actually done what you're thinking of. Unfortunately, if you want exact control of the positioning on any screen size, and an exact aspect ratio, then you're going to have to position resources programmatically. If you use xml, you can come pretty close, but won't have precise positioning control. For a beginner, positioning programmatically can be tedious. Since you're only positioning a couple of buttons here and there, it shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

How I did it: get the screenwidth and screenheight programmatically. Then calculate the aspect ratio of your button. Next, calculate the position of the button in relation to the screenwidth and screenheight (this would be in %). With all this info, you should be able to position buttons exactly where you want it on any screen size with a particular orientation. I would recommend positioning everything else on xml and do only the buttons programmatically. On orientation change, you will need to recalculate everything again, which can be annoying. I would recommend that you stick with 1 orientation and maybe support multiple orientations later.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually thinking of that, but dont know how and where to get and set the button properties in code. the layout is placed in a viewpager with a fragment pager adapter. Do i have to draw the layouts with xml, adjust the buttons (where?) and redraw the layouts, or do i have to add the buttons in code?

Comment: add the buttons in code. you can get references to the viewpager using findViewById and add the button to it using this reference.

Comment: Thanks! im going to try that.

Answer (score 0):

I use these helper functions to move my buttons around based on the percentage of the screen height and width. First I layout the screen for a 320 x 480 screen in graphical layout to create the xml, then move the buttons in my onCreate method.

Here are the imports I used:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
```

Here are the calls to move the buttons in onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    moveBtn(0.1843,0.1187,0.128,0.7375,R.id.credits_button);
    moveBtn(0.1843,0.1187,0.3125,0.7375,R.id.website_button);
    moveBtn(0.1843,0.1187,0.5,0.7375,R.id.facebook_button);
    moveBtn(0.1843,0.1187,0.6906,0.7375,R.id.support_button);
}
```

Here are the helper functions:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  public void moveBtn(double percent_width, double percent_height, double percent_x, double  percent_y, int myObject)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void moveBtn(double percent_width, double percent_height, double percent_x, double  percent_y, int myObject) {
    int width = (int)Math.round((ScWth(this) * percent_width));
    int height = (int)Math.round((ScHgt(this) * percent_height));
    int x = (int)Math.round((ScWth(this) * percent_x));
    int y = (int)Math.round((ScHgt(this) * percent_y));

     Log.d(TAG, "Object: " + myObject + "/Width: " + width + "/Height: "+ height + "/x: "+ x + "/y: "+ y);

    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams myParam = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, x, y); 

    Button thisButton = (Button)findViewById(myObject);
    thisButton.setLayoutParams(myParam);

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  public static double ScWth(Context context)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //return the screen width of the device
public static double ScWth(Context context){
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    return display.getWidth();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  public static double ScHgt(Context context)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //return the screen height of the device
public static double ScHgt(Context context){
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    return display.getHeight();
}
```

I hope it helps someone.